# Ganache not working

Tags: web3js, ether, ganache

I am developing on a testnet on ganache and using remix.
I am working with web3 and working on the user interface.

when trying to fetch a function with web3/ganache, I get the following error:
"ERRError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode".

The contract was deployed correctly and I even get results. But after a second or so, the message with the error comes. I call only a get function, nothing should have to change.

What could that be and what could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I have ran the function 10 times because I wanted to get the recent 10 articles. But the thing was, there were only 3 articles. So I accessed function getArticle(uint _id) with it 4 but there were only articles 0, 1, 2.